# Where in Kyoto can I visit a traditional wood workshop?

Tags: japan, sightseeing, kyoto

I'm taking my dad (an avid hobby wood worker) for a few days to Japan, specifically the Tokyo and Kyoto region. Would anyone have some recommendations or know of a traditional Japanese wood workshop that could be visited in that region?

Comment: Are you wanting one that speaks English? Because that will severely limit your options.

Comment: English is optional. We'd just like to take a look around and I find that communication generally ends up working somehow in Japan even if we don't speak the same language. Especially amongst fellow aficionados.

Comment: I found quite a few references to different workshops, however they are either private entities, companies or in a really obscure and hard to get to location. @AerisFang's answer below seems to be your best bet. When I lived in Kyoto I tried looking for something similar but never managed to find anything I could get to (I wanted to do carpentry but I lived in an apartment).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disclaimer: This isnt specifically in Kyoto. It's about 1h by train/car from Kyoto Station.

**The [Takenaka Carpentry Tools Museum](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attraction_Review-g298562-d7147573-Reviews-Takenaka_Carpentry_Tools_Museum-Kobe_Hyogo_Prefecture_Kinki.html) could be what you're looking for.**
It's located in Kobe, near Osaka.

[image]
<sub>(source: [dougukan.jp](http://www.dougukan.jp/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/img_%E6%9C%A8%E3%82%92%E5%88%BB%E3%82%801.jpg))</sub>

The museum features LOTS of information and displays on how woodworking and carpentry evolved from prehistoric Japan all the way to modern days. The building is gorgeous and there are plenty of examples of the different techniques demonstrated.

You can also borrow a very thorough audio guide that completes the visit very nicely (Which I highly recommend you do).

A bonus point is that, while in Kobe, you can eat some amazing Kobe Beef!